# how to accept filename from user and save the sound file in python

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, pyaudio

i am trying to record sound from pyaudio in python and making a gui for the same.
my code run fine when i use datetime library and give the filename eg.sound_2020_21_04_03_40.wav which is current date,time but when i try to take the filename from user with tkinter  (from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile) it is saving the sound file but its empty with 0 bytes.

can any on e  help me in this. this is my coding part of stop button which terminate the code and save the file.

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import pyaudio
import wave
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as font
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile

class App():
    chunk = 1024 
    sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16 
    channels = 2
    fs = 44100  

    frames = []  
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.isrecording = False
        myFont = font.Font(weight="bold")
        self.button1 = tk.Button(main, text='Record',command=self.startrecording,height=2,width=20,bg='#0052cc', fg='#ffffff')
        self.button2 = tk.Button(main, text='stop',command=self.stoprecording,height=2,width=20,bg='#0052cc', fg='#ffffff')
        self.button1['font'] = myFont
        self.button2['font'] = myFont
        self.button1.place(x=30, y=30)
        self.button2.place(x=280, y=30)

    def startrecording(self):
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  
        self.stream = self.p.open(format=self.sample_format,channels=self.channels,rate=self.fs,frames_per_buffer=self.chunk,input=True)
        self.isrecording = True

        print('Recording')
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.record)
        t.start()

    def stoprecording(self):
        self.isrecording = False
        print('recording complete')

        self.filename = asksaveasfile(initialdir = "/",title = "Save as",mode='w',filetypes = (("audio file","*.wav"),("all files","*.*")),defaultextension=".wav")

        wf = wave.open(self.filename, 'wb')
        wf.setnchannels(self.channels)
        wf.setsampwidth(self.p.get_sample_size(self.sample_format))
        wf.setframerate(self.fs)
        wf.writeframes(b''.join(self.frames))
        wf.close()
        main.destroy()
    def record(self):

        while self.isrecording:
            data = self.stream.read(self.chunk)
            self.frames.append(data)


main = tk.Tk()
main.title('recorder')
main.geometry('520x120')
app = App(main)
main.mainloop()
```

> image is here

[image: gui]

Comment: The empty file is created because `askopenfile(...)` creates a file after it is called. Your problem is that `pyaudio` doesn't save the file.

Comment: @DemianWolf   how can i resolve the issue.

Comment: You need to import `askopenfilename(...)` instead of `askopenfile(...)`. See details and the full code in the answer.

Comment: `wave.open(filename, ...)` filename can be string or file object.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that no exceptions were risen, because when you call `askopenfile(...)` it returns a **file object** (and opens an empty file for reading - that file you have seen), but `wave.open(...)` expects a **filename**. To get it, you need to use `askopenfilename(...)` instead of `askopenfile(...)`. And don't forget to import `askopenfilename` in the top of your code.

Here is the full code (I have refactored it according to PEP8):

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import pyaudio
import wave
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as font
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename


class App():
    chunk = 1024
    sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16
    channels = 2
    fs = 44100

    frames = []

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.isrecording = False
        myFont = font.Font(weight="bold")
        self.button1 = tk.Button(main, text='Record', command=self.startrecording,
                                 height=2, width=20, bg='#0052cc', fg='#ffffff')
        self.button2 = tk.Button(main, text='stop', command=self.stoprecording,
                                 height=2, width=20, bg='#0052cc', fg='#ffffff')
        self.button1['font'] = myFont
        self.button2['font'] = myFont
        self.button1.place(x=30, y=30)
        self.button2.place(x=280, y=30)

    def startrecording(self):
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = self.p.open(format=self.sample_format, channels=self.channels,
            rate=self.fs, frames_per_buffer=self.chunk, input=True)
        self.isrecording = True

        print('Recording')
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.record)
        t.start()

    def stoprecording(self):
        self.isrecording = False
        print('recording complete')

        self.filename = asksaveasfilename(initialdir="/", title="Save as",
            filetypes=(("audio file", "*.wav"), ("all files", "*.*")),
            defaultextension=".wav")

        wf = wave.open(self.filename, 'wb')
        wf.setnchannels(self.channels)
        wf.setsampwidth(self.p.get_sample_size(self.sample_format))
        wf.setframerate(self.fs)
        wf.writeframes(b''.join(self.frames))
        wf.close()
        main.destroy()

    def record(self):
        while self.isrecording:
            data = self.stream.read(self.chunk)
            self.frames.append(data)
            print("does it")


main = tk.Tk()
main.title('recorder')
main.geometry('520x120')
app = App(main)
main.mainloop()
```